# Prevent empty equations numbering?

Tags: align

```
\begin{align}
fdsafdsadf\\
\end{align}
```

will display two equation numbers. The trailing \ starts a new line... it is useful to add them so one can easily add or remove equations... or even comment them out(which then requires commenting out the \).

Answer (score 3):

This is really a long comment, but as I see it you have three options:

- there is no need to use `\\` at the end of an `align` environment as it already adds appropriate spacing (my recommendation!)
- if you really insist on using `\\` at the end of an `align` environment then use `\\ \notag` to suppress the equation number for the (unnecessary) empty line
- only use `align` for multi-line equations that need alignment and otherwise use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

These options produce, respectively:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  blah blah blah

  \begin{align}
  fdsafdsadf
  \end{align}

  blah blah blah

  \begin{align}
  fdsafdsadf\\\notag
  \end{align}

  blah blah blah

  \begin{equation}
  fdsafdsadf
  \end{equation}

  blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

with trailing \verb|\\|
\begin{align*}
fdsaf&=dsadf\\
fdsaf&=dsadf\\
\end{align*}
zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz 

without trailing \verb|\\|
\begin{align*}
fdsaf&=dsadf\\
fdsaf&=dsadf
\end{align*}
zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz 


\end{document}
```

As you can see from this un-numbered example, the trailing `\\` is wrong and badly affects the spacing, so just omitting the automatic number on the spurious line is not enough, you need to not have the line by not having a trailing `\\`. Also never use multi-line displays for single line equations, so for a single line you also need to change `align` to `equation`.